# My lights does not work unless you turn the stove on

Tags: light, stove

The stove controls the lights in the kitchen

Comment: Is this established behavior or was it always like that? If the first then find the fault, for the second get the lights fed from a different supply prior to the stove.

Comment: Are you all of a sudden having problems *all over the house*? Because that could be a lost neutral, which would be very serious. Or is this a "just the stove and kitchen lights" problem?

Comment: This would be really convenient if you needed to bake and didn't have time to turn on the lights.

Answer (score 8):

### Call the power company and report an outage

You lost one of your phases of power.   This is almost always a problem at the power company's end of the wire.

When you turn your oven on, it has the effect of connecting the dead phase to the still-live one.   However this gives very weak power on the dead phase, and this won't hold.

Go to your breaker panel and shut off all your double-wide (2-pole) breakers - oven, dryer, water heater, air conditioner etc.

Then call the power company and report the outage.  They should come out quickly (unless they're busy recovering from the bad weather of late), and the work will be free.

Comment: Is this different than a dropped neutral situation? In other questions it seems a dropped neutral is a serious emergency.

Comment: A dropped neutral and a dead phase are similar, in that both are power outage emergencies that need immediate attention from the utility company. They are different in that a dropped neutral is likely to overvoltage your 120V appliances, while a dead phase rarely might overcurrent the neutral wires in your MWBCs.

Comment: Yeah exactly@whatsisname... if you lose a phase, you can limp the house along for awhile on one leg using only 120V loads... but if you lose a neutral, you are sunk - you dare not use 120V loads or you'll fry stuff or start a fire.

Comment: Worst that could happen is the power company shows up & informs you the busted leg  is on your side of the box (relatively unlikely); then have an electrician fix it.